# The exit button of my MonoGame project does not work

Tags: c#, xna, exit, monogame

In my MonoGame project the red windows exit button suddenly stopped working. I'm not sure what change made the program behave so strangely, so I'm quite confused. 
Stopped working means, when I click on it literally nothing happens. The other Window buttons still work though! 
Also the rest of the game is fine as well.

I thought maybe I didn't close the spriteBatch somewhere, but also, this seems to be fine.

Then I thought it had to do something with the fact that I set the spriteBatch to static, so I changed everything back, but it still does not work.

Since I have no clue where the error could be, I will just link the project here and you can load it in vs and check if 
A) the error is only on my side somehow 
or 
B) What my mistake is

So here is the project: [My game project as .zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nqyczpn8gn3h857/Puzzelini.zip?dl=0)

Comment: To be honest, people won't download a whole project an go through it.

You best bet is to go back in your commit history until you find a version without the problem.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with you "red windows exit button" but exiting the programm is handled in line 147 of you game1.cs file. Place the debugger in the if statement and check if it gets executed. if not, then the key does not match Key.Escape

Comment: @PavelSlesinger I did not change those keys, so there is some exiting handled somewhere else as well. The red exit button I am talking about is the one provided bz default on ANY window, top right corner, red x.

Comment: @Aaron Ah, now I understand the issue. I doubt that this is an issue with monogame, since the window itself is created by the OS. You can create an empty monogame project (openGL at best) and test if the issue also exists. Finally you may ask your question on the monogame forums. the community there is quite active and helpfull.

Comment: @PavelSlesinger Okay, I'll ask at the MonoGame forums. When creating an empty project everything works fine, so it seems I created the porblem somewhere inside my programming.